# На лендинге не работает отправка информации на почту

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Мне достался сайт HTML, CSS, Javascript, без файла PHP, который отвечает за отправку информации на почту из форм обратного звонка. Я пытаюсь написать этот файл сам, но мне не хватает опыта. Письмо приходит на почту, поле "Имя" показано как нужно, но вот поля "Телефон" и "Вопрос" не хотят приходить. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

```js
/* Adding blocks, transform blocks, only for correct display */
$(document).ready(function() {
      var prefix = $('.prefix').val();
      var url = prefix + "respond.php";


      $('.button').click(function() {
        $('body').find('form:not(this)').children('label').removeClass('red');
        var request_url = '\n' + $('input[name="ref_url"]').val().toString().replace(/&/g, '\n');
        var utm_source = $('input[name="ref_url"]').val().match(/(?:utm_source=)(.*)(?:&utm_medium)/i);
        var utm_medium = $('input[name="ref_url"]').val().match(/(?:utm_medium=)(.*)(?:&utm_campaign)/i);
        var utm_campaign = $('input[name="ref_url"]').val().match(/(?:utm_campaign=)(.*)(?:&utm_term)/i);
        var utm_term = $('input[name="ref_url"]').val().match(/(?:utm_term=)([0-9a-zA-Zа-яА-Я%]{1,})/i);
        if (utm_source == null || utm_medium == null || utm_campaign == null || utm_term == null)
          var utms = '';
        else
          var utms = '\nutm_source=' + utm_source[1] + '\nutm_medium=' + utm_medium[1] + '\nutm_campaign=' + utm_campaign[1] + '\nutm_term=' + utm_term[1] + '\n';

        var answer = checkForm($(this).parent().get(0));
        if (answer != false) {

          var $form = $(this).parent(),
            name = $('input[name="name"]', $form).val(),
            phone = $('input[name="phone"]', $form).val() + ' ' + $('input[name="phone2"]', $form).val() + ' ' + $('input[name="phone3"]', $form).val(),
            email = $('input[name="email"]', $form).val(),
            usluga = $('input[name="usluga"]', $form).val(),
            referer = $('input[name="referer"]', $form).val(),
            phrase = $('input[name="phrase"]', $form).val(),
            ccall = $('input[name="ccall"]', $form).val(),
            ques = $('textarea[name="ques"]', $form).val(),
            sbt = $('input[type="button"]', $form).attr("name"),
            submit = $('input[name=' + sbt + ']', $form).val();
          var ref = $('input[name="referer"]').val();
          var ref = ref + '\nutm-метки:' + request_url;
          var formname = $('input[name="formname"]').val();
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            data: "name=" + name + "&usluga=" + usluga + "&referer=" + referer + "&phrase=" + phrase + "&ccall=" + ccall + "&phone=" + phone + "&" + sbt + "=" + submit + "&email=" + email + "&ques=" + ques + "&formname=" + formname + "&ref=" + ref
          }).always(function() {
            //метрики
            //ga('send', 'event', ''+sbt, ''+sbt, ''+sbt);
            thx();
          });
        }
      });
```

```html
<div class="popup" id="question">
  <div class="popup_h1">Задать вопрос</div>
  <div class="popup_h2">Оставьте заявку, и наш специалист
    <br />ответит на все интересующие вас вопросы</div>
  <form>
    <em>Имя</em>
    <label class="name left required">
      <input type="text" name="name" class="input_name" placeholder="Татьяна Иванова">
    </label>
    <br>
    <em>Телефон</em>
    <label class="phone2 top">
      <input type="text" name="phone" class="input_ph1" placeholder="8" value="8">
    </label>
    <label class="phone top required">
      <input type="text" name="phone2" class="input_ph2" placeholder="029">
    </label>
    <label class="phone top required">
      <input type="text" name="phone3" class="input_ph3" placeholder="4445544">
    </label>
    <br>
    <em>Ваш вопрос</em>
    <textarea name="ques" rows="4" placeholder="ваш вопрос"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input id=r3 name="referer" type="hidden" value="">
    <input id=n3 name="phrase" type="hidden" value="">
    <input name="ccall" type="hidden" value="3">

    <input name="question" type="button" class="bttn bttn2 button noselect" value="Задать вопрос">
  </form>
</div>
```

Это файл PHP который я пытаюсь написать:

```
 /* Здесь проверяется существование переменных */
  if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$name = $_POST['name'];}
  if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {$phone = $_POST['phone'];}
  if (isset($_POST['ques'])) {$phone = $_POST['ques'];}



/* Сюда впишите свою эл. почту */
 $address = "madest4815@gmail.com";

/* А здесь прописывается текст сообщения, \n - перенос строки */
 $mes = "Тема: Заказ обратного звонка!\nТелефон: $phone\nВопрос: $ques\nИмя: $name ";

/* А эта функция как раз занимается отправкой письма на указанный вами email */
$sub='Заказ'; //сабж
$email='Заказ <ОКНА ПВХ>'; // от кого
 $send = mail ($address,$sub,$mes,"Content-type:text/plain; charset = utf-8\r\nFrom:$email");

ini_set('short_open_tag', 'On');
header('Refresh: 3; URL=index.html');
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=index.htm">
<title>С вами свяжутся</title>
<meta name="generator">
<style type="text/css">
body
{

   background: #22BFF7 url(img/zakaz.jpg) top -70% center no-repeat;

}

<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout('location.replace("/index.htm")', 3000);
/*Изменить текущий адрес страницы через 3 секунды (3000 миллисекунд)*/
</script> 
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: вы проверяли на ваш рнр файл приходят переменные phone и ques ?

Comment: @HELOWORD Спасибо за Ваше внимание. Я не разбираюсь, подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: @HELOWORD Я не много не понял, что я скрыл. Мне нужны только поля - Имя, телефон и Вопрос.

Comment: попробуйте написать  if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$name = $_POST['name']; echo $name;}
  if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {$phone = $_POST['phone']; echo $phone;}
  if (isset($_POST['ques'])) {$phone = $_POST['ques']; echo $phone;}

Comment: @HELOWORD Вот что выдает - 
Тема: Заказ обратного звонка!
Телефон: undefined
Вопрос:
Имя: Gewrf

Comment: Телефон: undefined  пишет значит javascript не нашел вашу переменную Телефон

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте вот так отправить форму

```
  $('.button').click(function() {
     var msg   = $('#formx').serialize();
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'res.php',
              data: msg,
              success: function(data) {
                $('.results').html(data);
              },
              error:  function(xhr, str){
            alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
              }
            });

        }
```

потом на `php` проверьте существуют ли переменные

```
$name ="";
$phone ="";
$ques ="";

     if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$name = $_POST['name']; } 

        if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {$phone = $_POST['phone'];} 
        if (isset($_POST['phone2'])) {$phone.= $_POST['phone2'];}
        if (isset($_POST['phone3'])) {$phone.= $_POST['phone3'];} 

        if (isset($_POST['ques'])) {$ques = $_POST['ques'];  } 
echo  "name = ".$name."phone= ".$phone."ques= ".$ques;
```

Comment: Правка в javascript не понадобилась, достаточно было вставить ваш код в php. Спасибо большое за помощь!